# NSView preventing window/content view from resizing horizontally

Tags: macos, autolayout, nswindow, nsviewcontroller, osx-yosemite

I have an NSView inside my main view that is preventing my window/main view  from resizing correctly. Even when I go fullscreen, My main view can't fill the screen (there's some black space at the right). I know that the cause is that particular view (or something inside) as when I delete it my app behaves normally. What would cause an NSView to "control" growing of its window?

Here are the constraints on that view:

[image]

**UPDATE:** I've found an `NSTextField` inside which had hugging proiorty set to 750. I've taken it down to 250, now it DOES grow, but I can't shrink it down from "some" size. I'm calling it "some" size because it has nothing special: it's a bit less than my native fullscreen width, and it's different than my IB width.

Comment: In general, constraints with priorities higher than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut` (500) can force the size of a window. That includes the implicit constraints generated by intrinsic content size, if a view has such, which have the priorities set for content hugging and compression resistance. To debug, try logging `[window.contentView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal]` (or `...Vertical`, as appropriate). If you need help interpreting the output, add it to your question.

Comment: @KenThomases I see, then the horizontal compression resistance/hugging priorities of 750 were overriding default window size. Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, constraints with priorities higher than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut` (500) can force the size of a window. That includes the implicit constraints generated by intrinsic content size, if a view has such, which have the priorities set for content hugging and compression resistance.

So, if you have a text field whose horizontal content hugging priority is, say, 750 and there's a chain of constraints that connect its leading and trailing edges to the window's content view's edges (or, similarly, relate the text field's width to the content view's width), then the window won't be able to grow large enough to "stretch" that text field.

Likewise, if the text field's horizontal compression resistance is high, the window won't be able to shrink to the point where the text field would have to be compressed.